# Calculated fields in SimpleForm with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm new in ruby on rails and my problem is with using of SimpleForm. I want to have disabled field "Summary" which is disabled for editing by user and calculated from other fields on this same form if the input fields will be changed

Used formula: final_value = sumary - (err1+err2+err3)

My view code is

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@linka100, url: tesgal_linka100_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :sumary, "Summary" %>
  <%= f.number_field :sumary, min: 0, max: 9999, step: 1, only_integer: true %>

  <%= f.number_field :err_1, min: 0, max: 9999, step: 1, placeholder: "Err.1" %>
  <%= f.number_field :err_2, min: 0, max: 9999, step: 1, placeholder: "Err.2" %>
  <%= f.number_field :err_3, min: 0, max: 9999, step: 1, placeholder: "Err.3" %>
<%= f.label :final_value, "Final value" %>
  <%= f.number_field :final_value, min: 0, disabled: true, max: 9999, step: 1, **value: @linka100.sumary - (@linka100.err1 + @linka100.err2 + @linka100.err3)** %>
  <%= f.submit "Ulož údaje", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: you must use script!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the behavior of disabled, when you set a form field as disabled this value is not going to be sent to your controller. So you can use readonly instead.

Note: Notice that is possible from the client side to edit the values of the fields by editing the html on the browser, so always implement validations on the server side.

```
<%= f.number_field :final_value, min: 0, readonly: true, max: 9999, step: 1, **value: @linka100.sumary - (@linka100.err1 + @linka100.err2 + @linka100.err3)** %>
```